# creating a table to store data from SQL database

Tags: php, html

I am trying to store information from my database about a customers booked flights into a HTML table.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<h2> Your Flights: </h2>
    <table> 
    <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?> 
    <tr> 
    <th> flight number </th>
    <th> flight status </th>
    <th> flight destination </th>
    <th> booking date </th>
    <th> flight date </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td> <?php echo $row['flight_number'];?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['status']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['to_airport']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['booking_datetime']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['flight_datetime']; }?> </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
```

Currently it is repeating the table headers over again for each record from my database. I tried moving my while loop after my table headers however that just made the information go everywhere.

Comment: just move the while line, just after the header...

Answer (score 2):

```
<h2> Your Flights: </h2>
<table> 
<tr> 
<th> flight number </th>
<th> flight status </th>
<th> flight destination </th>
<th> booking date </th>
<th> flight date </th>
</tr>

<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?> 
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $row['flight_number'];?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $row['status']; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $row['to_airport']; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $row['booking_datetime']; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $row['flight_datetime']; ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop have to surround the `<tr>` including the data:

```
<h2> Your Flights:</h2>
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <th> flight number </th>
    <th> flight status </th>
    <th> flight destination </th>
    <th> booking date </th>
    <th> flight date </th>
  </tr>

  <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?><!-- start of while loop -->
  <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $row['flight_number']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['status']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['to_airport']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['booking_datetime']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['flight_datetime']; ?> </td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?><!-- end of while loop -->

</table>
```

You current code displays the header for each line because the `while` starts before the header. Your table is broken because you end the `while` loop inside the last column (after last value). So the closing tag of the last column and the row itself is missing.